# SQL query group by and where cause incorrect data to be returned

Tags: mysql, sql

Given the SQL code below:

```
create table A(a integer, b integer, c double);

insert into A(a, b, c)
values
(0, 0, 1.1),(1, 0, 1.2),(2, 0, 1.3),
(0, 1, 1.4),(1, 1, 1.5),(2, 1, 1.6),
(0, 2, 1.7),(1, 2, 1.8),(2, 2, 1.9),
(0, 0, 1.9),(1, 0, 1.8),(2, 0, 1.7),
(0, 1, 1.6),(1, 1, 1.5),(2, 1, 1.4),
(0, 2, 1.3),(1, 2, 1.2),(2, 2, 1.1)

mysql> select * from A where a = 0;
+------+------+------+
| a    | b    | c    |
+------+------+------+
|    0 |    0 |  1.1 |
|    0 |    1 |  1.4 |
|    0 |    2 |  1.7 |
|    0 |    0 |  1.9 |
|    0 |    1 |  1.6 |
|    0 |    2 |  1.3 |
+------+------+------+

mysql> select * from A where a = 0 group by b;
+------+------+------+
| a    | b    | c    |
+------+------+------+
|    0 |    0 |  1.1 |
|    0 |    1 |  1.4 |
|    0 |    2 |  1.7 |
+------+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why 3 rows? I would have thought both queries should return the same result since unique combinations of c exist.

Further

```
mysql> select *, sum(c) from A group by b;
+------+------+------+--------+
| a    | b    | c    | sum(c) |
+------+------+------+--------+
|    0 |    0 |  1.1 |      9 |
|    0 |    1 |  1.4 |      9 |
|    0 |    2 |  1.7 |      9 |
+------+------+------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

the sum seems to be the sum of all the rows rather than the sum of the groupings

Any ideas why I'm seeing this strange behaviour?

Comment: This would be invalid in all RDBMSs except MySQL. They would insist you `group by c` instead or include it in an aggregate.

Comment: all Data are coming perfectl you must give more time to  mysql

Comment: @Martin. I see, thanks. What would be the valid SQL for returning the sum of 'c' for each unique 'a'

Comment: @loudsight. You would add `SUM(c) AS sum_c` to the `SELECT` list.

Comment: If you want the correct result, do `select *, sum(c) from a where a = 0 group by b`. Note that column `c` will be selected at random because it is not pinned down in this query. If you want MySQL to force standard group by behaviour, see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by

Comment: You need `SELECT a,b,SUM(c) FROM A GROUP BY a,b`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html)** is clearly mentioned

> In standard SQL, a query that includes a GROUP BY clause cannot refer
> to nonaggregated columns in the select list that are not named in the
> GROUP BY clause. For example, this query is illegal in standard SQL
> because the name column in the select list does not appear in the
> GROUP BY:

```
SELECT o.custid, c.name, MAX(o.payment)
  FROM orders AS o, customers AS c
  WHERE o.custid = c.custid
  GROUP BY o.custid;
```

> For the query to be legal, the name column must be omitted from the
> select list or named in the GROUP BY clause.
>
> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to
> nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause.

**References:**

#### http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html

#### http://explainextended.com/2011/03/30/mysql-group-by-in-union/

#### http://20bits.com/articles/10-tips-for-optimizing-mysql-queries-that-dont-suck/

Comment: Despite that statement, there are different SQL standards and in newer standards you **CAN refer to nonaggregated columns in the select list that are not named in the GROUP BY clause**, as long as they are **functionally dependent on the columns that are named in the GROUP BY clause**. MySQL unfortuantely make no such restriction and allows any column to be in the SELECT list, regardless if it is dependent or not.

Answer (score 2):

Mysql is one of the few (are there any others?) databases that allow "illegal" SQL like this, where you have `group by` without aggregate functions on the other columns selected.

Instead of throwing an error, it returns the *first* row that meets the criteria, whatever that value for the grouped by column is.

Comment: What does "first" row mean? rows don't have any natural order.

Comment: @shef - As ordered by what? Is it deterministic?

Comment: @shef - So the first `c` value it encounters for each group in the execution of the query?

Comment: @Shef - Running a single query tells me nothing about the general behaviour. [This article](http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html) seems to imply "undefined" would definitely be a better choice of words. (See the end of the "Running into trouble with GROUP BY" section)

Comment: @Marting Smith: Actually you are right _["The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate."](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html)_ My rush into conclusion.